# How to run CakePHP app from subdirectory

Tags: php, configuration, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Using CakePHP 1.3, I have the following layout:

```
/srv/www/_cakephp13/
    /app/
    /cake/
    /plugins/
    /vendors/
    etc...

/srv/www/htdocs/  
    /cake_app/
    /other-dir/
```

... where `htdocs` is the public directory, and I have moved `webroot` of my app to be `cake_app` above... Which appears to be **almost** working. (After customizing webroot's index.php).

When I access `http://devserver/cake_app/`, I am able to see the default "Home" page controller/view (which I have customized, so *that* appears to be working).

But when I access `http://devserver/cake_app/controller/view` I am receiving **404** errors.

Is is possible to run a Cake App in a sub-directory of a site root? How can I get this working?

***Ideally***, I don't want to edit Apache conf's... If I can fix this with Cake configuration or htaccess files, I'll be much happier.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess? And which directory is it in?

Comment: They're all over the place, so which one? =) *htdocs* doesn't have one, *cake_app* and others within *_cakephp13* are the default files that unpack with Cake. I haven't edited them. The Apache Directory definition for *htdocs* has AllowOverride set to All.

Comment: The one in cake_app. You should verify that the .htaccess is being run and that rewrite is on and working. Run some tests to verify both those.

Comment: Ah-ha! So sorry to have posted this. 'rewrite' module was not installed, and furthermore 'FollowSymLinks' wasn't enabled appropriately. I could have sworn we'd recently been running pretty-urls via rewrite for some other sites on this server, which is why I didn't check. Shall I delete this question, or would someone like to *suggest* I check the aforementioned items? =)

Comment: I'll make my comment an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should verify that .htaccess is being run and that the rewrite module is on and working.

Comment: Accepted, because this was my particular issue. See my comment on the original post for more info.

Comment: Also rewritebase on .htaccess can cause troubles so it needs to be set correctly.

Comment: @dabito: Very true. Adding `Rewritebase /` solves configuration errors for many folks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have mod_rewrite enabled on Apache.  To check if it's on, make a page that just does this:

```
echo phpinfo():
```

Grep on the text "loaded modules".  Make sure mod_rewrite is listed there.  If it's not, you can either add it to apache's configuration, or you may need to install it (depending on your original installation method and whether you included that module).

If you can't get mod_rewrite running, you can still use cake without it (the URL will just look like index.php/controller/action/etc).  Check out http://book.cakephp.org/view/333/A-Note-on-mod_rewrite for more info.  Specifically,

> If you don't want or can't get
>   mod_rewrite (or some other compatible
>   module) up and running on your server,
>   you'll need to use Cake's built in
>   pretty URLs. In /app/config/core.php,
>   uncomment the line that looks like:
>
> Configure::write('App.baseUrl',
>   env('SCRIPT_NAME'));